# Calculation with in Bash Shell

Tags: bash, bc

How can I calculate following data?

```
Input:

2 Printers
2 x 2 Cartridges
2 Router
1 Cartridge
```

Output:

```
Total Number of Printers: 2
Total Number of Cartridges: 5 
Total Number of Router: 2
```

Please note that Cartridges have been multiplied `(2 x 2) + 1 = 5`. I tried following but not sure how to get the number when I have `(2 x 2)` type of scenario:

```
awk -F " " '{print $1}' Cartridges.txt >> Cartridges_count.txt
CartridgesCount=`( echo 0 ; sed 's/$/ +/' Cartridges_count.txt; echo p ) | dc`

echo "Total Number of Cartridges: $CartridgesCount"
```

Please advise.

Comment: I added a 'bc' tag to try to attract responses.

Comment: @noa `bash` has 3.7K followers, while `bc` has none. Adding that tag will attract zero extra responses.

Comment: This is really non-trivial for bash programming. Is this self-imposed pain, or are there external requirements that force you not to use a more powerful language ?

Comment: @chrisaycock: tags are also for searching, not just following.

Comment: Do you have a fixed set of inventory items that can occur in the input? If so, do they all have a mainstream regular plural?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this (assuming a well formatted input) ...

```
sed -e 's| x | * |' -e 's|^\([ 0-9+*/-]*\)|echo $((\1)) |' YourFileName | sh | awk '{a[$2]+=$1;} END {for (var in a) print a[var] " "var;}'
```

P.S. Cartridges and Cartridge are different. If you want to take care of that too, it would be even more difficult but you can modify the last awk in the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that there are only multiplication operators in the data.

```
awk '{$NF = $NF "s"; sub("ss$", "s", $NF); qty = $1; for (i = 2; i < NF; i++) {if ($i ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/) {qty *= $i}}; items[$NF] += qty} END {for (item in items) {print "Total number of", item ":", items[item]}}'
```

Broken out on multiple lines:

```
awk '{
        $NF = $NF "s"; 
        sub("ss$", "s", $NF); 
        qty = $1; 
        for (i = 2; i < NF; i++) {
            if ($i ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/) {
                qty *= $i
            }
        }; 
        items[$NF] += qty
     } 
     END {
         for (item in items) {
             print "Total number of", item ":", items[item]
         }
     }'
```